# Accessing elements of types with indexers using expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Suppose I have a type like this:

```
class Context
{
    SomeType[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to access specific `Items` elements using expression trees. Suppose I need an element at index `0`. I can do it like below, where everything works as expected:

```
var type = typeof (Context);
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (object));
var ctxExpr= Expression.Convert(param, context);    
var proInfo = type.GetProperty("Items");

Expression.ArrayIndex(Expression.Property(ctxExpr, proInfo), Expression.Constant(0));
```

If I change the context type to contain .NET provided `List<SomeType>`, instead of `array`, i.e.

```
class Context
{
    List<SomeType> Items { get; set; }
}
```

the same expression results in following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Argument must be array    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ArrayIndex(Expression array,
>   Expression index)

My question is, how to write respective expression which can access an item under appropriate index of `List<>`, or better - of any collection declaring indexer? E.g. is there is some way to detect, and convert such a collection to an `array` of appropriate types using expression trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An indexer is really just a property with an extra parameter, so you want:

```
var property = Expression.Property(ctxExpr, proInfo);
var indexed = Expression.Property(property, "Item", Expression.Constant(0));
```

where `"Item"` is the name of the [indexed property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

(If you don't know the name of the property beforehand, it's *usually* `Item` but you can always find it via reflection, by finding all properties with indexer parameters.)