# How to create dynamic NRules

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, nrules

I am getting this exception:

```
variable 'e' of type 'MyClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

I want to create dynamic rules with nested property. When I create static rules it works fine,  but not in dynamic mode. Also, I want to use expression for dynamic rules using these lines of code if possible:

```cs
PatternBuilder customerPattern = builder.LeftHandSide().Pattern(typeof(Customer), "customer");
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> customerCondition = customer => customer.Name == "John Do";
customerPattern.Condition(customerCondition);
```

I tried the code below to create and execute rules dynamically, but I am getting an exception. Why?

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CustomRuleRepository repository = new CustomRuleRepository();

            List<RuleEngineEntity> rules = new List<RuleEngineEntity>();
            rules.Add(new RuleEngineEntity { FieldName = "Age", Name = "CustomerCheck", Value = 20 });

            repository.LoadRules(rules);

            //Compile rules
            var factory = repository.Compile();

            //Create a working session
            var session = factory.CreateSession();

            RuleEngineRequestModel ruleEngineRequestModel = new RuleEngineRequestModel { ruleList = rules, customerData = new Customer { Name = "A", Age = 24 } };

            session.Insert(ruleEngineRequestModel);

            var IspassedorNot = session.Fire();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class RuleEngineRequestModel
{       
    public List<RuleEngineEntity> ruleList { get; set; }
    public Customer customerData { get; set; }
}

public class RuleEngineEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class CustomRuleRepository : IRuleRepository
{
    private readonly IRuleSet _ruleSet = new RuleSet("customerRule");

    public IEnumerable<IRuleSet> GetRuleSets()
    {
        return new[] {_ruleSet};
    }

    public void LoadRules(List<RuleEngineEntity> list)
    {
        _ruleSet.Add(
            BuildRule(list)
        );
    }

    public List<IRuleDefinition> BuildRule(List<RuleEngineEntity> list)
    {
        NRules.RuleModel.Builders.RuleBuilder builder = null;
        List<IRuleDefinition> rulesList = new List<IRuleDefinition>();
        builder = new NRules.RuleModel.Builders.RuleBuilder();
        builder.Name("CustomerDetail");
        ParameterExpression customerParameter = null;
        LambdaExpression customerCondition = null;
        PatternBuilder customerPattern = null;
        try
        {
            var orGroup = builder.LeftHandSide().Group(GroupType.Or);

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var andGroup = orGroup.Group(GroupType.And);

                customerPattern = andGroup.Pattern(typeof(RuleEngineRequestModel), item.Name);
                customerParameter = customerPattern.Declaration.ToParameterExpression();

                customerCondition =
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.GreaterThan(CreateParameterExpression(typeof(RuleEngineRequestModel), "customerData", typeof(Customer), item.FieldName),
                            Expression.Constant(item.Value)), customerParameter);
                customerPattern.Condition(customerCondition);
            }

            Expression<Action<IContext>> action =
                (ctx) => Console.WriteLine("Action triggered");

            builder.RightHandSide().Action(action);

            rulesList.Add(builder.Build());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return rulesList;
    }

    public Expression CreateParameterExpression(Type type, string propertyName, Type type2, string propertyName2)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(type, "e");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, type.GetProperty(propertyName));
        return Expression.Property(left, type2.GetProperty(propertyName2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `CreateParameterExpression` method, that's supposed to create a property access expression. But in that method you are creating a parameter expression there with a name "e", which does not correspond to any pattern that you defined in your rule. This causes the "variable not found" exception.

You simply need one MemberExpression to access the `customerData` property, and then another one to access the nested property, configured in the `RuleEngineEntity`.
Here is an updated `BuildRule` method that implements the necessary expression tree.

```cs
public List<IRuleDefinition> BuildRule(List<RuleEngineEntity> list)
{
    var builder = new NRules.RuleModel.Builders.RuleBuilder();
    builder.Name("CustomerDetail");

    var orGroup = builder.LeftHandSide().Group(GroupType.Or);

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var andGroup = orGroup.Group(GroupType.And);

        var modelPattern = andGroup.Pattern(typeof(RuleEngineRequestModel), item.Name);
        var modelParameter = modelPattern.Declaration.ToParameterExpression();
        var customerData = Expression.Property(modelParameter, nameof(RuleEngineRequestModel.customerData));

        var customerCondition = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.GreaterThan(
                    Expression.Property(customerData, item.FieldName),
                    Expression.Constant(item.Value)),
                modelParameter);
        modelPattern.Condition(customerCondition);
    }

    Expression<Action<IContext>> action =
        ctx => Console.WriteLine("Action triggered");

    builder.RightHandSide().Action(action);

    var rule = builder.Build();
    return new List<IRuleDefinition> {rule};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this will work if i have to access property from incoming Model, I tried your way earlier but my case is to access nested property so in this case it fails.Check my model and property i m accessing.

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh - ok, got it. I missed the customer was nested inside the model. The names of variables were misleading. I updated the answer with the reworked version of the BuildRule method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ^_^

Comment: One more question what if i change customerData as List, The model like below

Comment: public class RuleEngineRequestModel
{       
    public List<RuleEngineEntity> ruleList { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> customerData { get; set; }
}

Comment: also unable to bind current rule with action.

Comment: If you change the container to a List, you would need to create an expression tree that gets the customer from it, though it's unclear to me which customer - first or all of them.. And this mostly just becomes a general question about how to construct expression trees in C# to access values in a collection. There are plenty of answers on SO already, so I suggest you search and see if it's already answered. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924907/accessing-elements-of-types-with-indexers-using-expression-trees

Comment: Regarding "binding current rule with action" - not sure what you mean. If I compile and run your example with my changes on top, the rule fires and the action gets executed and prints "Action triggered"

Comment: Ok i'll look into this url provided by you for nested property with array list, again thanks for your help.

Comment: Not able to use Expression.ArrayIndex() how to make this indexer value dynamic so it checks all data in customerData

var dataList = Expression.ArrayIndex(customerData, Expression.Constant(0));
                var expres=Expression.Property(customerData, "Age");